# Attempted to restore registry from \Windows\System32\Config\RegBackup with xcopy. Got Share Violation error

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, windows-registry

I'm trying to save a windows 7 PC from reboot loop after using sysprep, I don't know if restoring the registry hives from a backup will help but I'm desperate, plus there is no restore point and the PC came with windows pre-installed so there is no install CD (I do have a separate windows install cd that I tried to use to get to startup repair menu, but it wouldn't let me as its not the original install CD?).

Since I can't get to the desktop I'm using Hiren's MiniXP to make changes.

as the title said I found this directory C:\Windows\System32\Config\RegBackup with backup hive files. I attempted to xcopy all the files to \Windows\System32\Config but it reported a share violation.

I have 2 questions. Is what I'm doing at all possible from Hiren's MiniXP and/or is there a better way considering the circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I used System Rescue CD which boots Gentoo and used that to replace the files. I assume its because Hiren's doesn't allow an elevated command prompt.